# Extending type in Breeze JS fails when using multiple entity managers

Tags: breeze

My application has multiple EntityManagers. When I extend a type, it works great with the first EntityManger, but with the second EntityManager, I get this error if I extend the same type:

> **Error: Metadata query failed for: /mytest/Metadata. Unable to either parse or import metadata: Cannot register the same constructor for MyPart in different metadata stores.  Please define a separate constructor for each metadata store.; Server side errors encountered - see the entityErrors collection on this object for more detail(…)**

What does this mean? How am I suppose to define separate constructors?

This is how I am extending entity:

```
entityManager.metadataStore.registerEntityTypeCtor("MyPart", MyPart);
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

When using [multiple EntityManagers](http://breeze.github.io/doc-cool-breezes/multiple-entitymanagers.html), you should use a single `MetadataStore` and share it among the EntityManagers.

This way, you only have to `registerEntityTypeCtor` once.

If you start with a single "masterManager" and load/register its metadata, then you can use masterManager.createEmptyCopy() to get a new, empty manager that has the same MetadataStore.